# How can I call a controller method in a view using ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a **controller** with a method that returns a value:

```
public float GetShoppingCartTotal()
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name;

        var total = _context.ShutterOrders.Where(c => c.User == user).Select(c => c.Price * c.Amount).Sum();

        return total;
    }
```

How can I call this method from a view so I can show its value, here is my **view** (P.S. I took out some code of the view since I think it really is unnecessary for the purpose of this question. I have marked the part where I would like to call my controller function):

```
@model IEnumerable<ShuttersInc.Areas.Identity.Data.ShutterOrders>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="text-right">Total:</td>
        <td class="text-right">
         **I'd like to place it here**
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

P.P.S - I have an IEnumerable model since I list items from a list. I think this is one of the main problems why I can't call the method from the controller, although I might be mistaken.

Comment: Generally speaking, you call a controller method in a view by doing a GET or POST to the corresponding URL.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  I know but I need a method from the controller that will return me a value on the view.

Comment: Then you should call the method on the controller **before** rendering the view, and store that value you're interested in into the view model you pass to the view

Comment: Or use a [web socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0).  It really kinda depends on what you want to accomplish

Comment: Please show the action where you get IEnumerable<ShuttersInc.Areas.Identity.Data.ShutterOrders>

Comment: you're trying to do it the wrong way. views should not know about controller. We should try to follow the correct pattern otherwise we'll make everything become messy.

Comment: you should refactor your code to put this `GetShoppingCartTotal` in a service. Then both your `controller` and `view` consume that service, actually view should not consume it but depend mainly on what the `controller` gives it. However in some flexible scenarios, it can go that way (hence the support of `@inject` directive in razor view in asp.net core).

Comment: Agree with marc_s, you can call the GetShoppingCartTotal method on the controller (HttpGet method) before rendering the view, then, use ViewBag or ViewData transfers the data from controller to view, and then, display them. Otherwise, you could use JQuery Ajax to call the GetShoppingCartTotal method, then, in the Ajax success function add the return data to the page.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you. I did it simply using a ViewBag and without a function. I placed the calculation in the index.

Comment: @ZhiLv Yup, it worked by just using a ViewBag. Very simple. Can't believe I was banging my head over something this simple lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrong solution must first in controller in action return view with modle:

```
public IActionResult  GetShoppingCartTotal()
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name;

        var total = _context.ShutterOrders.Where(c => c.User == user).Select(c 
        => c.Price * c.Amount).Sum();

        return View("viewName",total );
    }
```

then in view :

```
@model string
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="text-right">@Model</td>
        <td class="text-right">
         **I'd like to place it here**
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```